# How to post three nodes of same content type in three different blocks in the front page?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have already set the block regions in both my page--front.tpl.php and site.info files, created the custom content type and created the content that should be displayed on each of them....now how am I supposed to post this in the front page? I was told I should use Views for this with no much further explanation and I'm following some nodeone's screencasts on views... but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for here. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 separate block views, each will display 1 node. make sure they are offseted.

[image: 3 separate nodes]

*This will display 2nd top node of the content type 'automobile' that is promote to front page.*

Then configure them at admin/structure/block

Comment: thanks for the response... may I ask you how you chose the already published content?

Comment: in the view you click add, beside Filter criteria.  to publish a node its under the nodes publish settings

Comment: I think I'm getting there... however when I save this and place the views in the block regions I see this repeated in each block: Title Number 3
Title Number 2
Title Number 1  where what I want to do is to show each node content inside the block

Comment: The title doesn't matter.

Comment: I actually got to display the contents of the three adding the fields but how do I decide in which block I want such node to appear?

Comment: this display the 3 recent automobile publish to the front page.

Comment: YEah I know, I already figured out anyways... I pull them up with the nid. Thanks